# First few smallest Carmichael numbers congruent to $11 \pmod {12}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, carmichael-numbers

There are known to be infinite Carmichael numbers congruent to $a\pmod b$ for coprime integers $a$ and $b$. There are plenty of examples of small Carmichael numbers congruent to $1, 5, 7 \pmod {12}$, but what are the smallest examples $11\pmod {12}$? I couldn't find any on Richard Pinch's site, and also verified that if the smallest example is $C=p*q*r$, then $(p,q,r)>10000$. Any other further leads? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pulled [A205947](https://oeis.org/A205947) (Carmichael numbers not congruent to $1\bmod6$, which thus includes $11\bmod12$ numbers) and searched for those numbers congruent to $11\bmod12$. The first ten such numbers are
$$10546629279551$$
$$19177682527151$$
$$22799069430611$$
$$52305745012067$$
$$118069613866751$$
$$131314855918751$$
$$225053535639791$$
$$313608281158271$$
$$591537056799431$$
$$599075226610631$$
which are also the only such numbers below $10^{15}$.